# Delete first 15k lines of text file with Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, text, io

I have a large text log file (around 20MB). I would like to delete the first 15,000 lines or so. How can I do this in Node.js?

Comment: with shell just issue ...  tail -n +15000 < inputfilename  >  outputfilename ... if you must use Node.js then this will be a known good way to generate same outputfile

Comment: Why would you want to use Node.js for that? If it's a one off you can [use the shell for that](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37790/how-do-i-delete-the-first-n-lines-of-an-ascii-file-using-shell-commands).

Comment: It's a log file of the server, so I thought it would be nice for the server to keep only the most recent logs each day or so, and clear the rest, while having only one log file.

Comment: lets say you want just the last 10000 lines of a file ... tail -10000 < inputfile > outputfile

Comment: Yes, but why use Node.js for that? The shell has a solid and mature set of tools for processing text files and they're easy to automate using cron. Use them, not Node.js for that.

Answer (score 1):

You have to require [readLine](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#readline_example_read_file_stream_line_by_line) npm package.

```
const readline = require('readline');
const fs = require('fs');

const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: fs.createReadStream('sample.txt')
});

rl.on('line', (line) => {
  console.log(`Line from file: ${line}`);
//YOu can delete your line Here


});
```

Comment: How, that explanation is missing, deleting a line is using `line = ""`?

Answer (score -1):

I wouldn't recommend loading 20MB into memory for this task using NodeJS but if you know what you're doing then you can split the text by each line then splice it like so:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = '/some/path/here';

fs.readFile(path, (err, data) => {
    if(err) {
       // check for error here
    }
    let lines = data.split('\n');
    lines.splice(0, 15000); // from line 0 to 15000
    let splited = lines.join('\n'); // joined it from the lines array

    // Do whatever you want to do here.

    fs.writeFile(path, splited, err => {
       // handle error here
    });
})
```

Again, this is not really efficient so do it in your own risk :)